# Doctrine2 SELECT Query with JOIN

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have thoroughly scoured SO and Google however I can't find an answer to this very basic question.

I have the following entities in Symfony2

```
ADR\PortalBundle\Account
ADR\UserBundle\User (FOSUserBundle)
```

Each user has one account, and one account can have many users (all which seems to work fine elsewhere on the site).

I have the following query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT u, a
        FROM ADRUserBundle:User u
        JOIN ADRPortalBundle:Account a
        WHERE u.id = :userId'
        )->setParameter('userId', $this->getUser()->getId());
```

This returns me the single account data, as well as all accounts.

What I actually want is the account data for this particular user.

Having reversed the query so `FROM` is the account entity and `JOIN` is the user entity I get the reverse, a single account and all users in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because you are not actually joining tables on a specific field.

So you would need something like (I'm using u.account as the user property that references the account)

```
JOIN ADRPortalBundle:Account u.account a
```

You might also want to take a look at:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html.